# The verb for overtaking in a specific way

Tags: word-request, idioms, expressions, phrases

I am wondering what is the verb, expression or idiom which is used when a car tries to overtake its adjacent car and since there is another car ahead, the driver has to deviate their car and pass through the middle of those two cars.
Please take a look on the provided illustration.
[image]

I need to properly imply the message that:

- The car in the image is breaking the law. It is....... which is against the traffic rules.

PS. please note that the side from which the act of overtaking is occurring is not a matter of discussion here.

Comment: Fyi, we don't say to deviate a car. It's dangerous/illegal passing by cutting in front of another car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of saying it, ***to overtake***, is a proper way to say this. However, in AmE, most would call this ***to cut (off)*** and BrE is ***to cut (up)*** (thank you, Michael Harvey). Please view [section 5, AmE](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cut-off) and [section 2, BrE](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/cut-up_1).

AmE: "Hey! That car cut me off! Idiot."

BrE: "Hey! The wanker driving that car cut me up!"

or

AmE: "I need to avoid that car, so that it won't cut me off."

BrE: "I need to avoid that car, so it doesn't cut me up."

To describe that image - "The white car cut off the red car."

Have a good day!

Comment: In Britain, we might say that such a driver 'cut me up'.

Comment: The truck is not going to cut anyone off. The white car is cutting off the red car. Or illegally passing it.

Comment: In Britain, we tend to accuse a driver, not a car, of cutting-up.

Comment: Oh, okay! I will change that.